# ClipboardJS : Copy the content of a <code> section

Tags: javascript, clipboard.js

I need to copy the content of a `<code></code>` section using `ClipboardJS`. When following the tutorial, I end up with this error :

> Uncaught Error: Invalid "target" value, use a valid Element

Any workaround on this ?

EDIT:

**HTML**

```html
<code id="#foo">my fantastic code</code>
    <button class="copy-button" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#foo">
      Copy !
</button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  var clipboard = new Clipboard('.copy-button');

  clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
      console.info('Action:', e.action);
      console.info('Text:', e.text);
      console.info('Trigger:', e.trigger);

      e.clearSelection();
  });

  clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
      console.error('Action:', e.action);
      console.error('Trigger:', e.trigger);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Where is your actual code? It looks like you aren't selecting the element correctly. [You can see here](https://jsfiddle.net/qrjgb1Lv/) that it works fine on `code` elements.

Comment: @MikeC Thank you for your input. I edited with my code

Comment: You have a typo. It should be `<code id="foo">...`, not `<code id="#foo">...`

Answer (score 7):

Try to change this line:

```
<code id="#foo">my fantastic code</code>
```

for

```
<code id="foo">my fantastic code</code>
```

Comment: I'm so dumb. Thanks.